# How to use the Facebook API, and how can I post a link with status on the users wall via my app?

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to post a link + status through my app, using this "popup" Facebook window where the user is asked to log in, then asked to allow my app to his profile. Then I want him to be able to write a status, with a link I specify attached. This Facebook popup would be triggered by a button, not at start of my app (in the documentation I found that they want me to implement it in the `appDidFinish` launching method...) But I don't want that, I want it like the popup Facebook window is only triggered per button tap.

I'm trying to figure this out for a few days now, but finding that all tutorials are out-dated and the Facebook Developer documentation is very weak- at least for for me. I already downloaded the Facebook-iOS-SDK with the API and JSON included from GitHub. I already did a few attempts, but the furthest I got is that the user was asked to log in, but not through my app, instead Safari opened and the log in field were there, not in my app.

Could someone **please** post some code, a basic tutorial I might find helpful, or point me to a good online tutorial? I already tried to post to iPhone Dev SDK forums, where other people also asked for this, but never got any help. So could someone out here please put together something that would help out all the **newbies**?

I want my login screen look like this, and the rest should be in a popup too:
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=439332&l=c04b210914&id=100001688115647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a sample code in facebook-ios sdk you can see that there are already the code available for some things. Here is a code snippet from the older facebook API but this should work with the newer graph api too

```
- (void)setStatus:(id)target {
    NSString *statusString = @"Testing iPhone Connect SDK";
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            statusString, @"status",
                            @"true", @"status_includes_verb",
                            nil];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.users.setStatus" params:params];
}
```

WHat you can do is create a controller to handle all the facebook requests like a singleton class and on tap of button do something like this

```
- (IBAction)showFBLoginDialog:(id)sender {
    if(LoggedInFacebook == NO) {
        FBLoginDialog *dlg = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] initWithSession:faceBookController._session] autorelease];
        [dlg show];
    }
    else {
        [faceBookController logoutUser];
    }

}
```

If you need further help search on google and stackoverflow you will find a bunch of.

Comment: I already checked google, but I can't get smart out of it. Can you post some older threads that would help me? **AND** I can't build the demo app, even though I provided the App ID

Comment: What errors you are getting when you build demo app? you can see source code in demo app atleast and use in your app.

Comment: missing app ID although i put it into the plist with "fb12345678910"

Comment: app Id you need to put in code search for it you will find it defined somewhere as macro.

Comment: add now by the way, initWithSession is not even available as I look at it. Now the SDK only contains these classes (both .m and .h): Facebook, FBConnect, FBDialog, FBLoginDialog and FBRequest.
**So how should I implement the FBSession?** Ive seen it in other samples (non working now) and it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: @Martin Herman No Actually that time I was in office. I'll send you code right now.

Comment: but I sent on the mail address you have written here. check your spam folder

Comment: @Martinko sent to this one too